# Excel Formula within same workbook but 3 sheets need to compare one column on 2 sheets annd place number from 3rd column into sheet 3

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 3 sheets in an excel workbook, I want to compare Colum C from sheet 1 with Column C sheet 2, if the same number exist anywhere then I want the value of Column G from sheet 2 to be palced into Column G on sheet 3

Comment: In the column C comparison, do the matching values have to be on the same row?  Ie if Sheet1!C5 = 270, does that match with 270 anywhere in column C of Sheet2, or only in Sheet2!C5?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have sheet1:

```
a b  1
a b  2
a b  3
a b  4
a b  5
```

And sheet2:

```
a b  6  ... x
a b  2  ... gg
a b  7  ... x
a b  5  ... zz
a b  8  ... x
```

And so, on sheet3 you want (with or without columns A..F)

```
a b  2  ... gg
a b  5  ... zz
```

**Easiest solution but with some manual operation:**

Add a column in sheet2, with the following formula (assuming headers in row 1)

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100000,0)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Add a filter to the sheet2 and filter for TRUE's.
Copy and paste to sheet3

**Using formulas only (no manual copy and paste):**

"If true then copy" as a FORMULA doesn't exist natively in excel. It would require that a cell with a formula can change the value in another cell (not just its own value). This is counter to the way a spreadsheet works and would lead to all kinds of nasty circular logic and slow computations. Rather imagine you are entering a formula into the cell that you want to copy to (Sheet3!G2...). This formula can look to column Sheet2!G and *reference* its value (but not hard copy).

So, you could put in Sheet3!G2:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!C2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100000,0)),"",Sheet2!G2)
```

You will have your comparison data, but also lots of empty rows where no matches occurred. You could again add a filter to get rid of the blanks.

To solve this problem completely using formula only, you must number the matches in sheet2 like this:

```
a b  6  ... x  0
a b  2  ... gg 1
a b  7  ... x  1
a b  5  ... zz 2
a b  8  ... x  2
```

Using this formula in Sheet2 column H, starting at H2:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100000,0)),IF(ROW() = 2,0,H1+1), IF(ROW() = 2,1,H1+1))
```

Then lookup those matches using INDEX, MATCH and ROW functions in sheet3 column G, starting in G2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$100000,MATCH(ROW()-1,Sheet2!$H$2:$H$100000,0))
```

Comment: Thanks you I will try all these option you have outlined. Some manual is fine, but prefer all formula as there are over 300 entries